# Apache - puma reverse proxy failing

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a puma server and an apache server running on the same computer.
I am trying to implement a reverse proxy in apache to forward example.mooo.com/redmine to the puma server (listening to localhost:9292)

My .conf file for apache is the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.mooo.com
    ServerAlias example.mooo.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.key
    <Location "/redmine/">
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:9292"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:9292/"
        Substitute "s|http://localhost:9292/|https://example.mooo.com/redmine/|i"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this config the browser can load the first page, but without the styles and all the links are pointing to `http://example.mooo.com/xxx` instead of `http://example.mooo.com/redmine/xxx`

Comment: did you tried without subtitute ? did you tried only `RewriteRule /redmine/(.*) http://localhost:9292/$1 [P]` instead of all thoose location stuff ?

Comment: It has to be a typo: on `ProxyPass` there is no trailing slash, while on `ProxyPassReverse` there is one.

Comment: @473183469 I tried with and without trailing slash at the end of `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. No change.

Comment: @Froggiz In fact Substitute doesn't change anything. whether it is here or not I have the same behaviour. If I understand correctly, the RewriteRule  you propose will perform the redirection (it would alter only incoming requests). The redirection is not the problem here, and it is exactly what apache is advising not to do : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/avoid.html

Comment: it is about testing, anyway did you checked your browser log at least ?

Comment: @Froggiz I understand. I tried the `RewriteRule` alone and it generates an "page not found", so i reverted back to what is in my original post. Something surprising is that the request for .css and .js in the apache logs seems correct but returns a 404 :  `... "GET /javascripts/application.js HTTP/1.1" 404 482 "https://example.mooo.com/redmine/" ...`

Comment: Although when I enter `https://example.mooo.com/redmine/javascripts/application.js` in my browser I have no problem to download the file.

Comment: could you try `<Files "/redmine/*">` instead of `<Location "/redmine/">` ?

Comment: `ProxyPass cannot occur within <Files> section` :-(

Comment: Strangely, the source of the page downloaded with firefox looks like the susbtitution did'nt worked, but the very same page downloaded with wget shows the `/redmine/, as if the the susbstitution worked. Same behaviour after I cleared FF's cache.

Comment: does http://localhost:9292/javascripts/application.js works ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31181/discussion-between-quentin-and-froggiz).